# Why has there been no moon for 2 nights straight

Tags: solar-system

I have been watching the sky all night for a week now I see flying stars everywhere well things that look like stars, what are they? And the moon has been gone for two nights now? Why?

Comment: That's two questions. Please limit to one and give a much better description of what you actually see.

Comment: It would help to know where you are. And when you say "all night" what actual range of times are you talking about? Really dusk till dawn?

Comment: All night, or each night before going to bed? There was a full moon five days ago where much of the world got to see a lunar eclipse. Moonrise and sunset occur at more or less the same time on the day of a full moon. Moonrise occurs later and later on the days that follow, shifting about 47 minutes every day. That means that four days after a full moon, there are about three hours between sunset and moonrise.

Comment: If you look for the moon at the same time every night, you'll see the Moon at various phases for about 14 days and then, no moon or 14 days.    If you spend an hour before you go to bed each night, you might see the Moon for 15 days and then not see it for 13.   The moon should be visible most nights provided you know what time to look for it.   But before bed is too small a window.  The moon will fairly often not be visible during your window for a week or more.

Comment: It might help us shape our advice if you could tell us your age.

Comment: I'm gonna stretch the rules here and let this question stand (I've even replied). Seems like OP genuinely wants to learn, so why not lend them a hand.

Answer (score 2):

The Moon is out of sight for a few nights every four weeks, more or less. It moves around the sky slowly. Sometimes it's far from the Sun (as seen from our planet), and that's when you see it at night, up in the sky. Other times it seems close to the Sun, and then of course you won't see it at night. Then the cycle repeats, over and over again. Takes a bit over 4 weeks to repeat.

The star-like things moving in the sky can be many things. Usually they are satellites in orbit around Earth, or airplanes flying at high altitude.